# SYNTAX ERROR - Can't assign to operator in setting variables

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have this Syntax Error in IDLE:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

This then highlights the end of a line, line 2 of the following code:

```
date              = "Unknown"
day-of-week       = "Unknown"     
time              = "Unknown"
week              = "Unknown"
```

I would appreciate any help I can get with this :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why python does not allow hyphens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064329/why-python-does-not-allow-hyphens)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python is interpreting `day-of-week` as "day" minus "of" minus "week". Try using `day_of_week` instead.

Sample code to show this.

```
>>> day = 3
>>> of = 2
>>> week = 4
>>> day-of-week
-3
```

Answer (score 2):

"Day-of-week" is an invalid variable name, and you can't use the minus sign on the left side of an assignment operation.

Your code is the equivalent of:

```
 day - of - week = "unknown"
```

Try

```
day_of_week = "unknown"
```

Instead!