# Django forms and recaptcha - change class name

Tags: python, django, django-forms, recaptcha

I am building an contact form with django 1.9 . My form has default inputs (fullname, email, phone, message).

To make it easier for coders forms.py:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):

full_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Full Name')}),
                            error_messages={'required': _('Full Name is missing')}, label=_('Full Name'))
phone = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Phone')}), label=_('Phone'))
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('E-mail')}),
                         error_messages={'required': _('E-mail is missing!'), 'invalid': _('Insert a valid e-mail address!')}, label=_('E-mail'))
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 9}),
                          error_messages={'required': _('Message is missing!')}, label=_('Messages'))
```

To fight against bots and spam, I've added [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) to the template which is succesfully working.

In my view, I am first checking for POST request, then the contact form and model are defined (Model is needed for storing the contact messages to DB). As next, I validate recaptcha through grecaptcha_verify (just ignore it).

After that, the validation success check goes through

```
if request.POST:
    contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    contact = Contact()
    r = grecaptcha_verify(request)
    if contact_form.is_valid() and r["success"]:
        context = {
            'full_name' : contact_form.cleaned_data['full_name'],
            'email' : contact_form.cleaned_data['email'],
            'phone' : contact_form.cleaned_data['phone'],
            'message' : contact_form.cleaned_data['message'],
        }
```

In my template, the captcha div is added within the form.

```
<div class="large-12 columns">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeNhyUTAAAAAN7KdVt8FLoxlVwAYY2zPVUEy7wu"></div>
</div>
```

For now, everthing works fine. But I want to check if the visitor who sent the request has at least sent the g-recaptcha-response in the POST request. I could do that simply. But the problem begins here.

In **forms.py**, if a validation for a parameter is needed, you need to define a variable with its name and parameters (**i.E.**     full_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Full Name')}) ... )
But as it was already told, python treats hyphens as [operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064329/why-python-does-not-allow-hyphens). So the next option that came to my mind is: why would I simply change the reCAPTCHA class name. Of course, changing it by default name 'g-recaptcha' to any other class, would not work. As I looked up in reCAPTCHA documentation, I did'nt sadly find any possibility to change the class name. So I am stuck between two specific requirements.

For now, I found a **temporary** solution.

In forms.py, I defined a new variable with name 'recaptcha' - which is valid.

```
recaptcha = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': _('hidden')}), required=False)
```

** required is set to false

In the template, in the position where recaptcha is found, I've added error alerts for recaptcha tag:

```
        {{ form.recaptcha }}
                {% if form.errors.recaptcha %}
                <div data-alert class="alert callout" data-closable="slide-out-right">
                    {{form.errors.recaptcha.as_text}}
                    <button class="close-button" aria-label="Dismiss alert" type="button" data-close>
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
```

In views.py, I added two if statements:

```
if not request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response'):
    contact_form.add_error('recaptcha','No g-captcha-response')
elif not r["success"]:
    contact_form.add_error('recaptcha','Captcha verification not successfull')
```

This works, but is some kind of tricking django validation by injecting errors based on request.POST of the g-recaptcha-response parameter.

Is there any possibility to change the class of `g-recaptcha`, so django forms can load it without hyphen issue?

Comment: You might find it easier to use the [django-recaptcha](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha) package.

Comment: If you want a simple math captcha, here is an easily implementable one: https://github.com/alsoicode/django-simple-math-captcha

Comment: Using plugins will make the same result while validating. The point is to: create an form validation name that will accept 'g-recaptcha-response' or a possibility to change the reCAPTCHA class name/POST parameter...