# time data conversion missing microseconds in gm time python

Tags: python, time

I am converting some date time, but I got a problem. the date time is

```
my_time = "2012-03-18 14:50:36.90"
```

my code to convert this date time is

```
import time
import datetime
import calendar

time_con = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
final_time = calendar.timegm(time_con.timetuple())
```

when print, i got

```
>> print "time_con", time_con

datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 18, 14, 50, 36, 900000)
```

when I print final_time , I got

```
>> print "final_time", final_time
1332082236
```

I am unable to get milliseconds, and I don,t know how to deal with them properly because I need those milliseconds in my date time. I search SO but no clue. but in Can help would be great and it will save my day. thanks

Comment: `dat-time` is an invalid variable name in Python.

Comment: @linusg  I change variable name. thanx a lot , but problem still exists.

Comment: `my-time`, too the dash is not allowed.

Comment: @linusg I hope now its fine. thanx for the pointing my mistakes.

Comment: Look, this will never ever run and therefore not work. `final-time` has ... a dash in it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064329/why-python-does-not-allow-hyphens if still don't believe)

Comment: @linusg thanx . I got the point. Actually I changed the names of variables, therefore I make mistakes. but I learn now and i make corrections accordingly.

Comment: Fine! I'm halv on a solution, wait a sec.

Comment: See my answer below, which is different from ForceBru and shows it is indeed possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to solve. Since you have not the milliseconds but microseconds stored in `time_con`, we can do `time_con.microsecond*1000` to get milliseconds.

```
import time
import datetime
import calendar

my_time = "2012-03-18 14:50:36.90"
time_con = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
microsecs =  time_con.microsecond
final_time = calendar.timegm(time_con.timetuple())*1000000 + millisecs
# final_time is in microseconds

# To print in seconds
# print(final_time/1000000)

print(final_time)
```

Results in

```
1332082236900
```

Which is hopefully what you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: i will implement and will come back in a moment. thanx alott

Comment: thanx a lot for the help. its my extremely silly mistake. %f mean micro. so I was talking about microseconds. can you change it accordingly so that I accept your answer. because your solutions works perfectly fine for milliseconds.

Comment: thanx a lot for the help and precious time.

Comment: thanx , i will come back in a moment.

Comment: @ i accept your answer because it works fine. thanx a lot for the help.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the last print, fixed now, so give it a try ;)

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help! Happy coding :D

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 you can do

```
import datetime

my_time = "2012-03-18 14:50:36.90"
time_con = datetime.datetime.strptime(my_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
final_time = time_con.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
# 1332082236.9
```

[Here is the link to `datetime.datetime.timestamp`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp).

Comment: I am using python 2+.  but thanx a lot. I learn this new thing for python 3.

Comment: Right! I noticed that a bit late, well, here it stays for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) for `calendar.timegm` (emphasis mine):

> `calendar.timegm(tuple)`
>
> An unrelated but handy function that takes a time tuple such as returned by the `gmtime()` function in the time module, and returns the corresponding **Unix timestamp value**, assuming an epoch of 1970, and the POSIX encoding.

The [UNIX timestamp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is *defined* to be a non-negative integer. Well, Wikipedia says that it can be floating-point, but anyways, UNIX systems normally represent it with a variable of C type `time_t`, which is whole non-negative. An *integer*, because it's meant to represent the number of seconds passed since the beginning of the UNIX epoch.

So, it clearly cannot represent milliseconds because it's defined to be a whole number.