# What is the easiest way to load hdf5 chunks to a single variable in python?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Now I have a bunch of hdf5 chunks, their structures are all the same. And I would load them as a whole in python, is there any easiest way?

(For now, I'd have to use `for` loop to load them file by file and then concatenate together, but I believe this seems dumb and there should be something easier to use).

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Have you written any code? Also, what do you mean by "chunks"? (FYI chunks has a specific meaning with HDF5: it designates _**chunked storage**_ of a dataset.) I suspect you mean you have "_a bunch of **HDF5 files**_". If so, please share basic info about schema and dataset dtype/shape.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Combine Two HDF5 Datasets without intermediate buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025342/how-to-combine-two-hdf5-datasets-without-intermediate-buffer)

Comment: @kcw78 In the end I just wrote `for` loop in python, but not as done by that. I use a lot cache to make it easier for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

we could use the `.copy` method in `h5py`.

Answered by:
[How to Combine Two HDF5 Datasets without intermediate buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68025342/how-to-combine-two-hdf5-datasets-without-intermediate-buffer)