# Python Argument Parser - the following arguments are reqired --name

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

When I run the following code:

```
def read_args():
    parser = default_parser()
    parser.add_argument('--tensorboard-dir', type=str, default='/tmp/cifar10/tensorboard')
    parser.add_argument('-N', type=int, default=50000, help="Use N training examples.")

    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    flags = readargs()
```

I have the following error output:

The following arguments are required: --name

[image: Error Output]

However when I add the --name argument:

```
def read_args():
    parser = default_parser()
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, default='cifar10test')
    parser.add_argument('--tensorboard-dir', type=str, default='/tmp/cifar10/tensorboard')
    parser.add_argument('-N', type=int, default=50000, help="Use N training examples.")

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    flags = readargs()
```

is also creating problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `default_parser`? How exactly are you running this? and lastly, the error doesn't say you need to **define** the argument `name`, rather to **add** it in your command line call. If you mean you *literaly* run the above code, then no arguments are passed. change to `parser.parse_args([...])` and fill the list with the arguments you want to pass (all strings)

Comment: The error shows a 'usage' as well.  What is it?

Comment: error means that you have to run script as `script.py --name some_value` .  Probably in `default_parser()` you have `add_argument('--name', ...)`. Run `script.py --help` to see all arguments.

Comment: When you tried to add your own `--name` argument, what was the error?  I suspect it complained about a conflicting definition.  That would confirm the idea that `default_parser` has already defined a `--name` (as required).

Comment: @Tomerikoo Dear Tomerikoo, default parser method contains a massive amount of argument variables, and I did not add it, because I thought it might be confusing. Would you like me to add the default_parser method?

Comment: @AhmetTavli No, no need to put it all here. Simply check if there is already a `--name` argument there, which is most likely the case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `default_parser` contains a `--name` argument which is required. What you're doing in your second example is defining the argument twice - once in `default_parser` and once in your program. Instead, you should be passing a `--name` argument when calling your program from the command line.

Example:

```
python cifar.py -N=1200 --tensorboard-dir=file.txt --name=cool_name
```

Alternatively, you could remove `default_parser` and construct your own ArgumentParser:

```
`parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()`
```

Full working demo:

```
import argparse

def read_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--tensorboard-dir', type=str,
                        default='/tmp/cifar10/tensorboard')
     parser.add_argument('-N', type=int, default=50000,
                         help="Use N training examples.")

     return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    flags = vars(read_args())
    # You can access your args as a dictionary
    for key in flags:
        print("{} is {}".format(key, flags[key]))

main()
```

The parser returns a [Namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object, but we can access its (much simpler) internal dictionary using `vars(Namespace)`. You can then get your arguments by accessing the dictionary, for example, `flags['N']`. Note that `tensorboard-dir` becomes `tensorboard_dir` inside your python program [to avoid issues with the subtraction operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064358/11598475).

Call it from the command line (I'm using Bash):

```
python cifar.py -N=1200 --tensorboard-dir=file.txt
```

Output:

```
tensorboard_dir is file.txt
N is 1200
```

Comment: As someone pointed out in the comments on the question, I guess you're importing `default_parser()` from elsewhere. If you include the source then someone can help out, but I'm guessing it has a required `--name` argument. If so, you need to be adding that argument when calling the program from the command line, not trying to override it by adding it as another argument.

Comment: He doesn't need to do the `sys.argv[1:]` stuff, because that's the default.  `print(flags)` is enough to see the Namespace.  But none of that addresses the '--name' error.

Comment: Given he had no idea what `--name` was and wasn't referencing it anywhere else, I assumed he didn't want it and was just reusing a piece of code. You're right about `sys.argv` (I'm not very familiar with argparse) - I'm updating the answer entirely to reflect that.