# SyntaxError: can't assign to operator about booleans

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I got a SyntaxError: can't assign to operator when I typed in a boolean. How can I fixed it? Below is the code that popped a error:

```
Super-Sport = False
                  ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I expect it will run smoothly, but it didn't

Comment: See [Why python does not allow hyphens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064329/why-python-does-not-allow-hyphens)

Answer (score 0):

Change `Super-Sport` to `Super_Sport` (or `SuperSport` etc). Python is interpreting the `-` as `minus` and causing your syntax error.